# Dynamic subdomains in yii2 and ISPmanager Lite

Tags: apache, .htaccess, yii2

I want to make dynamic sub-domains with region like **albuquerque.site.ru** and all this must go to one index.php on the server.

In the yii2 `main.php` config i have something `'https://<region:\w+>.site.ru' => 'site/index'`

In the ISPmanager settings i added alias *.site.ru and also in DNS i added A record *.site.ru.

But now if i go to **albuquerque.site.ru** im getting system 404 error.

I'm new on server administrating. 
Is there any mistake i did or something i did wrong in settings?

***UPD*** Turned off the `autosubdomain` options, now i'm getting white page.

Comment: How does this "404 error" looks like? It is Yii error page or webserver error page?

Comment: @rob006 It's an apache erorr. `Apache/2.4.27 (Debian) Server at albuquerque.site.ru Port 80`

Comment: `Not Found The requested URL / was not found on this server. Apache/2.4.27 (Debian) Server at albuquerque.site.ru Port 80`

Comment: White page usually means fatal error - you should take a look into error log to find a clue what is the source of it.